# avoid NullPointerException at the first cycle

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this piece of code:

```
EventSnapshot snapshotEvent = new EventSnapshot();

EventSnapshot currentEvent = new EventSnapshot();

do
{
   ...              
currentEvent.setContent(in_stats); 
   ...              
if(!snapshotEvent.equals(currentEvent))
    snapshotEvent.setContent(in_stats);
}
while(true);
```

At the first cycle I get a `NullPointerException` because obviously the object snapshotEvent is empty. At the second cycle this doesn't happen.how can avoid this problem?

**EDIT**

this is the error and it happens here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.w3c.jigmonitor.EventSnapshot.equals(EventSnapshot.java:40)



public class EventSnapshot 
{
    private Statistics content;

    public EventSnapshot()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @return the content
     */
    public Statistics getContent() 
    {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * @param content the content to set
     */
    public void setContent(Statistics content) 
    {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean equals(EventSnapshot es)
    {
        return this.content.equals(es.getContent()); // here...
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EventSnapshot [content=" + content + "]";
    }   
}
```

Comment: due to `snapshotEvent = new EventSnapshot()` isn't null...

Comment: Nothing is "obvious" from the code you've given. `snapshotEvent` isn't null - you've set it to a non-null reference in the very first line. Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: NullPointerException raised on the lower level than you demonstrated in the source code.

Comment: the code is very long...I will spend tiime to reduce and get the problem

Comment: @user1508419: Answered. This is why it's so important to provide short but complete programs demonstrating the problem - we couldn't possibly have diagnosed this from the information in the initial qusetion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EventSnapshot.equals` method is broken - it will throw an exception if `content` is null.

*Either* make sure that a snapshot never has null content, *or* change `equals` to look like this:

```
public boolean equals(EventSnapshot es) {
    // TODO: Decide how to handle the situation where es itself is null
    if (content == es.getContent()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (content == null || es.getContent() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return content.equals(es.getContent());
}
```

Note that it's somewhat odd to provide a new `equals()` overload without *also* overriding `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if statement:

```
if(snapshotEvent!= null && !snapshotEvent.equals(currentEvent))
    snapshotEvent.setContent(in_stats);
}
```

**EDIT**:

After your edit, the error is happening in the equals method:

```
public boolean equals(EventSnapshot es)
    {
        return this.content.equals(es.getContent()); // here...
    }
```

It can be caused by two factors:

1. `this.content` is null
2. `es` is null

Just log it or debug it and see which is true

Answer (score 0):

It is not the `snapshotEvent` that is `null` but it's content: `snapshotEvent.content`.
You can change the `equals` method to:

```
public boolean equals(EventSnapshot es)
{
   if(es == null) return false;
   if(content == null) return false;
   if(es.content == null) return false;
   return this.content.equals(es.getContent()); // here...
}
```

Comment: I understood that null is Statistics content but how can avoid this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You need to check, if shapshotEvent != null or catch NullPointerException with empty block.

Comment: Catching NullPointers doesn't actually *fix* them. It merely hides them from view further up the call stack. Fundamentally, a NullPointerException indicates an issue with control flow of the program so catching them is very rarely (if ever) the right thing to do (adjusting control flow to ensure they do not happen is better).

Answer (score -1):

From the code you supplied it's hard to tell what causes that NullpointerException. But you could always just catch it and let your code go to the next iteration; maybe that solves it:

```
EventSnapshot snapshotEvent = new EventSnapshot();
EventSnapshot currentEvent = new EventSnapshot();
do {
    try {
        ...              
        currentEvent.setContent(in_stats); 
        ...              
        if(!snapshotEvent.equals(currentEvent))
            snapshotEvent.setContent(in_stats);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
} while(true);
```

Comment: Absolutely not. A `NullPointerException` represents a *bug*. Catching and ignoring exceptions is a *horrible* thing to do, and in many cases could end up destroying data. You should only generally catch `Exception` at a high level of the stack, e.g. in order to prevent one bug from bringing down a whole server - but you would effectively abort that *request* or user action. Just continuing is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet I disagree with you on this. Catching and ignoring exceptions **might** be a horrible thing to do. There might be situations where a `NullPointerException` is not good but "ok"

Comment: Well, of course it's better to find the cause and solve that. But if you never use "quick fixes" we wouldn't be getting anywhere soon.